# loading 3D model with background in windows form

Tags: c#, model, 3d, xna, xna-3.0

I have made an application in XNA 3.1 in which a model is being loaded in picture box in windows form, which is working just fine: below is the code for Game1 class.
Now I tried to load multiple models in that for that I refered to an application of `WinFormControlLoading`, here I want to know that to write instead of modelviewcontrol line or where do I call the LoadContent function which calls my model

```
void LoadModel(string fileName)
{
    Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

    string buildError = contentBuilder.Build();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(buildError))
    {
        // If the build succeeded, use the ContentManager to
        // load the temporary .xnb file that we just created.
       modelViewerControl.Model = contentManager.Load<Model>("Model");
    }
    else
    {
        // If the build failed, display an error message.
        MessageBox.Show(buildError, "Error");
    }

    Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
}
```

In this line error occurs

```
modelViewerControl.Model = contentManager.Load<Model>("Model");
```

when i changed my Game1 class function of LoadContent to public like

```
Game1 game;
game.LoadContent = contentManager.Load<Model>("Model");
```

I get error of

> Error 1   'WindowsGame1.Game1.LoadContent()': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'protected' inherited member 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.LoadContent()'

How I solve this?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know in which class you are doing this, but this class has to inherit from `GameComponent` or `DrawableGameComponent`, in this way you can use the ContentManager like this:

```
Game.Content.Load<Model>("Model");
```

Comment: and i am doing it behind my form where i want to show my rendering model with texture .

Comment: either i am not getting where to do that exactly or i might have not explained the problem correctly. i linked two applications one which i made on xna that shows a renderable 3D model in windows form picture box control with background as well and other which is only using windows form an already prepared application, which imports all models and stuff in windows form and shows but in 'Model View Controller' tool which i don't want to use